# efficient way to get values from object based on id list

Tags: javascript

I have list of `users`:

```
users: Array<any> = [{id:1,name:'A'},{id:2,name:'B'},{id:3,name:'C'}];
```

and

```
this.selectedUsers = [1,2];
```

How do I get all the objects from the `users` array having an `id` found in the `selectUsers` array?

Comment: Define "efficient".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should do what you want:

```
var found = this.users.filter(
    item => this.selectedUsers.some(id => item.id == id)
)
```

**update**

```
var found = this.users.filter(
    item => this.selectedUsers.some(id => item.id == id)
).forEach(item => {
  item.label = item.name;
  item.name = undefined;
});
```

or

```
var found = this.users.filter(
    item => this.selectedUsers.some(id => item.id == id)
).map(item => {id: item.id, label: item.name});
```

Comment: this is working fine. But Can I return matching object as {id:1,label:'A'}. ie changing name property with label?

Comment: I updated my answer with two ways. The first modifies the data, the 2nd creates new objects that match the desired structure.

Answer (score 2):

You may use indexOf with filter.

```
this.users.filter(user => this.selectedUsers.indexOf(user.id ) > -1)
```